# Auto Restore DHCP Backup on Microsoft DHCP Server When Restart (Windows Server 2019)

Tags: dhcp-server, windows-server-2019

I have a Windows Server 2019 with DHCP Server installed and a scope configured. To protect the scope from accidental misconfigurations or disasters, I'd like to set a protection method so when I restarted the DHCP Server, It will restore the previous DHCP Backup automatically and continue in normal operation.

I have search for this feature in DHCP Server Manager but there is no option to do this protection method.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

It is be possible to [export and import DHCP server configuration](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/networking/netsh-utility-export-import-dhcp-scopes) using netsh, which is a handy option when migrating the DHCP role from one server to another.

```
netsh dhcp server export C:\dhcp.txt all
netsh dhcp server import C:\dhcp.txt all
```

However, there should not normally be such problems when just restarting the DHCP server, and automating the imports might actually cause more misconfigurations than it prevents: you would probably end up restoring an older backup than the current configuration. You should only restore the configuration from backups when you notice there is a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Don't do this. You risk doing more harm than good. In fact, I don't see any good in it at all.

If the DHCP database is being backed up, and the server is being backed up, then you should be able to restore the DHCP database from any of a number pf previous backups **IF AND WHEN** you need to.